# Encryption code in python, call upon a function, python returns nothing. No error messages show

Tags: python, encryption

Okay, so I've written the following series of functions in Python 3.6.0:

```
def code_char(c, key):
  result = ord(c) + key
  if c.isupper():
    while result > ord("Z"):
        result -= 26
    while result < ord("A"):
        result += 26
    return chr(result)
  else:
    while result > ord("z"):
        result -= 26
    while result < ord("a"):
        result += 26
  result = chr(result)
  return result

def isletter(char):
    if 65 <= ord(char) <= 90 or 97<= ord(char) <= 122:
            return True
    else:
            return False

def encrypt(string, key):
    result = ""
    length = len(string)
    key = key * (length // len(key)) + key[0:(length % len(key))]
    for i in range(0,length):
            if (isletter for i in string):
                    c = string[i]
                    num = int("".join("".join(i) for i in key))
                    result += code_char(c, num)
            else:
                    c = string[i]
                    result += i
    return result
```

Then I try to call on the functions with:

```
encrypt("This is a secret message!!", "12345678")
```

When python runs the program absolutely nothing happens. Nothing gets returned, and in the shell python forces me onto a blank line without indents, or >>>. i don't know what is right or wrong with the code as no error messages appear, and no results appear. Any kind of advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think you function `isletter` better than the standard `isalpha`?

Comment: Back to your question: One of your `while` loops, possibly more than one,  is infinite.

Comment: @DYZ I avoided using the standard `isalpha` because this was a requirement of the assignment given. Thank you for the `while` loop advice. I shall try that now to see if it fixes my problem.

Comment: `if (isletter for i in string):` isn't doing anything useful. The generator in the parenthesis doesn't call `isletter()`, it just creates a list of pointers to the isletter function. This always evaluates to `True`. Maybe what you really want is `if isletter(string[i]):`

Comment: @Craig Thank you for pointing that out, I completely overlooked that. The `if isletter(string[i]):` is much better, seeings as it actually does something. Thank you.

Comment: Your problem is probably in this line: `num = int("".join("".join(i) for i in key))` as it ends up with `num` having the value `12345678123456781234567812`, which _might_ be what you want, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, I don't think this is an infinite loop. I think your loop will not be infinite but will run for a very long time since the value of `key` is very big, and so, subtracting 26 at a time, until it gets to an English letter ascii value, will just take forever (but not really forever)

```
>>> key = '12345678'
>>> length = len("This is a secret message!!")
>>> key * (length // len(key)) + key[0:(length % len(key))]
'12345678123456781234567812'
```

It might be a problem in the your logic, maybe in the logic generating the key, but if this is indeed the logic you want, how about using modulus rather than iterating:

```
def code_char(c, key):
    result = ord(c) + key
    if c.isupper():
        if result > ord("Z"):
            result = ord("Z") + result % 26 - 26
        if result < ord("A"):
            result = ord("A") - result % 26 + 26
        return chr(result)
    else:
        if result > ord("z"):
            result = ord("z") + result % 26 - 26
        if result < ord("a"):
            result = ord("a") - result % 26 + 26

    return chr(result)

def isletter(char):
    if 65 <= ord(char) <= 90 or 97<= ord(char) <= 122:
            return True
    else:
            return False

def encrypt(string, key):
    result = ""
    length = len(string)
    key = key * (length // len(key)) + key[0:(length % len(key))]
    for i in range(0,length):
            if (isletter for i in string):
                    c = string[i]
                    num = int("".join("".join(i) for i in key))
                    result += code_char(c, num)
            else:
                    c = string[i]
                    result += i
    return result


>>> encrypt("This is a secret message!!", "12345678")
'Rlmwrmwrerwigvixrqiwwekiss'
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. I'm trying to have each index of the key be the shift key for the respective index of the string, rather than each index of the string be shifted by the entire key. I must be doing something else wrong then. Thank you for the advice though!

Comment: @TwoFourSixOhOne  , see my modified response and comments above. I believe your code's key is too large  to be solved just by just substracting. You may want to look at other avenues, possible using some linear algebra or crypt/decrypt modules.

Answer (score 0):

Should you be having `while` loop here , or are you intening `if` loop? I don't see any exit for while loop. That may be where your code is hanging.

```
if c.isupper():
    while result > ord("Z"):
        result -= 26
    while result < ord("A"):
        result += 26
    return chr(result)
  else:
    while result > ord("z"):
        result -= 26
    while result < ord("a"):
        result += 26
```

Also, if I replace `while` with `if` above, it's giving me overflow error.

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

**EDIT**
After looking at @polo's comment and taking a second look at code, I believe @polo is correct. I put `while` loop back and added `print` statements. I have commented them, but you can uncomment at your end.
I've also reduced key's complexity to just `key = key` and reduced key from `12345678` to just `1234` to see if the code works and if it completes in reasonable time.. You can make it as complex as you want once  code runs smoothly.

Here is result I got after:

```
>>> 
key =1234
coding char = T
coding char = h
coding char = i
coding char = s
coding char =  
coding char = i
coding char = s
coding char =  
coding char = a
coding char =  
coding char = s
coding char = e
coding char = c
coding char = r
coding char = e
coding char = t
coding char =  
coding char = m
coding char = e
coding char = s
coding char = s
coding char = a
coding char = g
coding char = e
coding char = !
coding char = !
encrypted_message = Ftuezuezmzeqodqfzyqeemsqaa
```

Modified code below:

```
def code_char(c, key):
  result = ord(c) + key
  if c.isupper():
    while result > ord("Z"):
        #print("result1 = {}",format(result))
        result -=  26 
    while result < ord("A"):
        #print("result2 = {}",format(result))
        result += 26
    return chr(result)
  else:
    while result > ord("z"):
        #print("result3 = {}",format(result))
        result -= 26
    while result < ord("a"):
        #print("result4 = {}",format(result))
        result += 26
  result = chr(result)
  return result

def isletter(char):
    if 65 <= ord(char) <= 90 or 97<= ord(char) <= 122:
            return True
    else:
            return False

def encrypt(string, key):
    result = ""
    length = len(string)
    #key = key * (length // len(key)) + key[0:(length % len(key))]    
    key = key
    print "key ={}".format(key)
    for i in range(0,length):
            if (isletter for i in string):
                    c = string[i]
                    num = int("".join("".join(i) for i in key))
                    print("coding char = {}".format(c))
                    result += code_char(c, num)
            else:
                    c = string[i]
                    result += i
    return result

#encrypt("This is a secret message!!", "12345678")
encrypted_message = encrypt("This is a secret message!!", "1234")
print("encrypted_message = {}".format(encrypted_message))
```

Comment: @ Anil_M I have now replaced the `while` with `if`, and am now recieving the same error message! Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Anil_M if you replace while with if, you will try to convert result to chat when it is still very big, much bigger than the range limitation of chr(). If you print your result before you call chr function, you can see the number you're trying to convert and test yourself in the interpreter. I'm not sure why it raises an Overflow error rather than a ValueError

Comment: @TwoFourSixOhOne , your code and logic is good. main problem is you are making too big and the further making bigger after  merging with length of input string. I've simplified key and put print statements to see if the code works. It does work as intended. You may want to work on parsing the key more efficiently. Probably post another question on SO on just how to do that.

Comment: @polo, Yes, I realized that after taking another look. Fixed the code and simplified key to yield a encrypted message.